How to get access rights to mount folder?
Step 1:
I have created a folder called "/media/test" with mkdir /media/test.
Now I have full access to the folder (e.g. I can create subfolders or files).
Step 2:
During boot a NFS share is mounted to that folder (via fstab). Here's the line:
192.168.178.163:/test /media/test nfs rw,hard,intr,tcp,timeo=14 0 0

Now I cannot do anything with the folder anymore. E.g. mkdir /media/test/foo now gives me a permission denied error.
How can I get access to the folder again? Do I have to mount it differently?
PS:
I also tried
192.168.178.163:/test /media/test nfs rw,hard,intr,tcp,timeo=14,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0

but this does not change anything. Folder access is still denied.

you've not granted the permissions for the share such as in this entry in my fstab line provides `uid=1000,gid=500" right at the end of the entry as in (my case) //192.168.1.117/[share_name] [/mount_point] cifs username=[user_name},password=[password],rw,uid=1000,gid=500

I added ",uid=1000,gid=1000" to the fstab entry options, then did a reboot. But the problem remains.

run sudo mount -a -v and see what errors it throws up
